# Bottle Framework PUT request

Tags: python, bottle

This is my Bottle code

```
import sqlite3
import json
from bottle import route, run, request

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
       d = {}
       for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
               d[col[0]] = row[idx]
       return d

def db_connect():
       conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
       conn.row_factory = dict_factory
       return conn, conn.cursor()

@route('/inventory', method='GET')
def get_inventory():
    conn,c=db_connect()
    c.execute("SELECT id, name, category, location, date, amount FROM inventory")
    result = c.fetchall()
    json_result=json.dumps(result)
    return json_result

@route('/inventory/get/:id', method='GET')
def get_item(id):
    conn,c=db_connect()
    c.execute("SELECT id, name, category, location, date, amount FROM inventory WHERE id=?",(id, ))
    result=c.fetchall()
    json_result=json.dumps(result)
    return json_result

@route('/inventory/new', method='POST')
def add_item():
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    category = request.POST.get('category')
    location = request.POST.get('location')
    date = request.POST.get('date')
    amount = request.POST.get('amount')
    conn,c=db_connect()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO inventory (name, category, location, date, amount) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", (name,category,location,date,amount))
    new_id = c.lastrowid
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    return '<p>The entry with id %d has been added to the database</p>' %new_id

@route('/inventory/delete/:id', method='DELETE')
def delete_item(id):
    conn,c=db_connect()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM inventory WHERE id =?", (id, ))
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
    return 'The entry with id %s has been deleted from the database' %id

@route('/inventory/edit/:id', method='PUT')
def edit_item(id):
    name = request.PUT.get('name')
    category = request.PUT.get('category')
    amount = request.PUT.get('location')
    location = request.PUT.get('date')
    date = request.PUT.get('amount')
    conn,c=db_connect()
    c.execute("UPDATE Inventory SET name=?, category=?, location=?, date=?, amount=? WHERE id=?", (name, category, location, date, amount,id))
    conn.commit()
    c.close();
    return '<p>The entry with id %s has been edited in the database</p>' %id


run(reloader=True)
```

I am trying to make the make the edit_item method to work.
When I call it with curl
`curl -X PUT -d "name=aa&category=bb&amount=23&location=xx&date=21-10-2014" http://localhost:8080/inventory/edit/2`

I get a server error which says

> raise AttributeError('Atrribute %r is not defined.' % name)
>   AttributeError: Attribute 'PUT' not defined'
>   What should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this,

```
name = request.PUT.get('name')
```

use this:

```
name = request.params.get('name')
```